# Processing multiline variable in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I have extracted the results of a query in a variable.

```
echo "$a"
TABLESPACE_NAME                  TOT_SIZE   PCT_FREE    DATAFILE
------------------------------ ---------- ----------    -----------
SYSTEM                               1000     40.625    /u01/oracle/datafile1.dbf
SYSAUX                               1000    67.2375    /u01/oracle/datafile2.dbf
USERS                                  55 96.3636364    /u01/oracle/datafile3.dbf
UNDOTBS1                             1000    98.0625    /u01/oracle/datafile4.dbf
```

I need to check the location of datafile (`/u01/oracle`) for space ,then add a datafile for each tablespace.

**Basically what im trying to do is :-**

```
 loop
 extract location from 4th col
 check for space availability
```

could you please suggest how to proceed.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Table space name is SYSTEM and datafile name is /u01/oracle/datafile1.dbf

Comment: Also can we store the rows in an array.If yes please share as im  new to shell scripting

Comment: that can be different so i have to check location for all the rows

Comment: Edit your question and provide details of your expected output and how that output should be generated.

Comment: Expected Output
---------------------
Table space name is SYSTEM and datafile name is /u01/oracle/datafile1.dbf
Table space name is SYSAUX and datafile name is /u01/oracle/datafile2.dbf
Table space name is USERS and datafile name is /u01/oracle/datafile3.dbf
Table space name is UNDOTBS1 and datafile name is /u01/oracle/datafile4.dbf

I want to do this with the help of array.
any other solutions are also welcome.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple awk command to print 1st and last columns for each row for the row # greater than two:

```
echo "$a" | awk 'NR>2 {printf "Table space name: %s and datafile name: %s\n", $1, $NF}'
```

This will print table name and datafile for each record.

Comment: Can i store the value of rows in a variable. for example a=SYSTEM ,b=1000,c-40.65 and d=/u01/oracle/datafile1.dbf.

Comment: There will be multiple values in this output but you can store whole output using `out=$(echo "$a" | awk 'NR>2 {printf "Table space name: %s and datafile name: %s\n", $1, $NF}')`

Comment: Thanks this was really helpful.!!

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on **tick mark** on top-left of my answer.